# Uri constructor throws exception for relative path without UriKind

Tags: c#, .net, uri

Why is

```
 new Uri("temp/file.txt")
```

throwing the following exception

> UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

instead of creating a relative `Uri`? It doesn't know the format so why do I need to specify the `UriKind.Relative` argument? It still doesn't know the format when I do it. This is counterintuitive.

Is there a way to create a relative `Uri` without having to use the `UriKind` argument? Having to do this untermines the purpose of the `Uri` class because I now cannot use it for *implicit* `string --> Uri` converstion without checking the `string` myself each time.

Comment: `var uri = new Uri("temp/file.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to create it by specifying `RelativeOrAbsolute` as [`UriKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.urikind?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var uri = new Uri("temp/file.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: oh boy, this is an unexpected solution... this should be the default.